# How I can make a project for win phone 8 in delphi 2010?

Tags: delphi, windows-phone-8

I want to make a application for windows phone 8 OS in delphi 2010.

Comment: Windows phone 8 OS is not supported by Delphi.

Answer (score 3):

Delphi does not target Windows Phone. At the moment, as of XE5, Delphi targets:

- Desktop Windows, x86 and x64 (not WinRT)
- Mac OSX, x86
- iOS
- Android (ARM)

There is no support for Windows Phone and to the best of my knowledge, none is in the offing. The Delphi cross-platform strategy is based on FireMonkey and that's not easy to take to Windows Phone.

As for Delphi 2010, that supports but a single platform: desktop Windows x86.

If you want to use Pascal to make Windows Phone apps then Oxygene from RemObjects is what you need. If that's not attractive to you then the MS tooling based on C# is the most obvious option that remains.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can't. You need to use the Windows Phone SDK which only works with Visual Studio.

If you install the SDK, you get a free Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone, who you can use to develop any type of app (free or not)

Comment: This answer is factually incorrect. Windows Phone development is not restricted to Visual Studio.

Comment: Are you sure that the Windows phone SDK is the only way to create WinPhone Apps, make some searches before answering

Comment: I don't think you can develop for Windows Phone 8 without the SDK. Xamarin Studio support Android,iOs an Mac, not Windows Phone. PhoneGap for Windows Phone need wp sdk. For Oxygen you need Visual Studio Also. I would like to know how to develop for Windows Phone and compile apps without Windows Phone SDK and Visual Studio. It could be interesting

Comment: Oxygene uses VS as its IDE, but you can build from the command line without VS.

Comment: Ok, you don't need to use the IDE, but you actually need to install Windows Phone 8 SDK... i don't see the difference but... ok, good to know.

Comment: You are right, maybe i don't explain good enought my answer. I'm not worried about the downvote, thanks for the explanation :)